# How can i solve blurry text in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When i open any app in my windows 10, the texts and images display in blur, can anyone help me fix it?

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]

here's my system's information:
[image: screenshot 4]

Thanks for you, i found a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1163657/rdp-to-windows-10-blurry?rq=1)

Comment: Please provide information on your system’s hardware. Does this issue affect the entire Windows GUI (including the taskbar and window borders)? Does it affect the lock/login screens? If you have a compatible device handy: Does it also appear when accessing your system via RDP?

Comment: I edited the Question and provided information on my system, Yes affect the entire Windows GUI. @DanielB

Comment: Well rather than some `dxdiag` screenshots, I was thinking of a complete listing. However, this looks like a laptop. Please try and find out its service tag, configuration code or whatever and provide that.

Comment: Do you mean this ? 
SerialNumber PF0NBCVD  @DanielB

Comment: Looks like a bad case of Intel GPU's acceleration issues. For me it only happens in Visual Studio and disabling hardware acceleration for UI drawing solves it. It also affected Blink-based browsers at some point, but it got fixed. I have never seen it happening in Windows UI, though. Anyway, try updating your display drivers.

Comment: Why did you supply the same image twice?

Comment: @ZeyadEtman It's great you found a solution yourself. In that case you should answer your own question and then mark the question as solved by selecting your own answer. Please note that link-only answers are generally not considered acceptable, so quote the text too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, the setting is located within Intel HD Graphics Control Panel on your host machine.

[image]

[This answer posted here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1163657)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have scaling enabled? If you right-click on the desktop, then click Display Settings, is Scaling and Layout set to 100%?
If you've changed the scaling and haven't signed out, it can affect the display. 
Also, when you're not at the native resolution, you can see some blurring.

Comment: As you can see from the pictures, this is clearly not about scaling.