# RDP session freezes when dialog box pops up

Tags: windows-10, macos, remote-desktop, lan, vlan

This is actually a contribution to this question: [Remote Desktop intermittently freezing](https://superuser.com/questions/1481191/remote-desktop-intermittently-freezing) but I can't post on that one due to having just registered

Host: Windows 10 version 2004 (insider preview)
Client: MacOS 10.14.6, Microsoft RDP Client 10.3.9
Devices are on same physical LAN, different VLANs

Anyway, I am not able to apply the suggested fixes because my client is a Mac. For me at least it occurs whenever a dialog box box pops up. I think it somehow has to do with focus being shifted without user input. I have no idea what significance that might have vis-a-vis RDP, but I am able replicate it pretty reliably

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be with the audio driver. When the dialogue box appears, it usually comes with a sound. So you have to disable the audio in the RDP client.

Steps:

- Right-click on the particular RDP client in the list
- Click "Edit"
- Click "Devices & Audio"
- At the section "Play Sound", choose "Never"

Comment: This works. My scenario: I have multiple remote Windows 10 pro, and latest Microsoft Remote Desktop app on MacOS (Ventura, but symptom was present before Ventura). I suggest OP accept answer.